# Can set some type for FormControl value?

Tags: angular, typescript, form-control

Framework which I use (Angular 7).

I want set some type for FormControl like this.

```
    startDate: FormControl<NgbDate>;
    endDate: FormControl<NgbDate>;
```

Do you have any experience with it or it is not posible in angular?

Comment: You can take a look to https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form we've added some type safety, not perfect but it'll at least catch that a form shape has changed when you do a refactor for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For now it's not possibile. Check this issue to Angular GitHub [Reactive forms are not strongly typed](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13721)

Comment: This is possible beginning with Angular 14, and is available now to preview in `14.0.0-next.12` or higher.

Answer (score 0):

It is available in angular 14 ,

```js
startDate: FormControl<Date | null>(null);
endDate: FormControl<Date | null>(null);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).